# Convert javascript button to URL button

Tags: javascript, lightning-experience, button

I have a javascript button which is a list button with following javascript.

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Property__c)}; 
if (records.length > 0) {

    //perform logic to concatenate the strind Ids to pass in the url

    window.location.href = "/apex/PropertyMassUpdate?property.ids=" + s 
    +"&returnUrl=" +window.location.href ; 
}
```

When List button is clicked a piece of code will concatenate the selected ids in a string and pass it in the url parameter. Now I need to convert this page to LEX. Since in LEX the javascript button will not show up, I am trying to convert this button to URL button. How can I get the concatenated list of selected ids   that I can pass in the url?
Any suggestions, links please.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

@Quest_sfdc, Javascript buttons ARE NOT available in Lightning Experience as Action Buttons. Salesforce has some [Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration) that should point you how they suggest best-practices for replacing Javascript buttons going forward.

Comment: @jordan.bauke, yes I am aware of that. That's why the architect wants to convert in url button which works perfectly fine in LEX.

Comment: @Quest_sfdc the `Custom Visualforce Buttons` section in the Trailhead module Jordan linked above has exactly what you're searching for.

Comment: I just went through the TrailHead and got the idea. Can anyone please give an example/tutorial on how to create mass action to get selected records?